# Boost Accumulators Tail Template Argument Invalid

Tags: boost, tail

I am a newbie to using boost accumulators.  I have tried a simple program using examples from the boost website.  I have something as simple as:

```
#include <boost/accumulators/accumulators.hpp>
#include <boost/accumulators/statistics/stats.hpp>
#include <boost/accumulators/statistics/tail.hpp>
include <boost/accumulators/statistics/tail_quantile.hpp>
using namespace boost::accumulators;

typedef accumulator_set<double, stats<tag::tail_quantile<right> > > accumulator_t_right;
typedef accumulator_set<double, stats<tag::tail_quantile<left> > > accumulator_t_left;

accumulator_t_right acc0( tag::tail<right>::cache_size = 1000 );
accumulator_t_right acc1( tag::tail<right>::cache_size = 1000 );
accumulator_t_left  acc2( tag::tail<left>::cache_size = 1000 );
accumulator_t_left  acc3( tag::tail<left>::cache_size = 1000 );
```

I am met with:

/usr/local/src/freeswitch/src/mod/applications/mod_soundtouch/mod_soundtouch.cpp:56:63: error: template argument 1 is invalid
/usr/local/src/freeswitch/src/mod/applications/mod_soundtouch/mod_soundtouch.cpp:56:65: error: template argument 1 is invalid
/usr/local/src/freeswitch/src/mod/applications/mod_soundtouch/mod_soundtouch.cpp:56:67: error: template argument 2 is invalid
/usr/local/src/freeswitch/src/mod/applications/mod_soundtouch/mod_soundtouch.cpp:56:88: error: invalid type in declaration before ';' token
/usr/local/src/freeswitch/src/mod/applications/mod_soundtouch/mod_soundtouch.cpp:57:62: error: template argument 1 is invalid
/usr/local/src/freeswitch/src/mod/applications/mod_soundtouch/mod_soundtouch.cpp:57:64: error: template argument 1 is invalid
/usr/local/src/freeswitch/src/mod/applications/mod_soundtouch/mod_soundtouch.cpp:57:66: error: template argument 2 is invalid
/usr/local/src/freeswitch/src/mod/applications/mod_soundtouch/mod_soundtouch.cpp:57:86: error: invalid type in declaration before ';' token
/usr/local/src/freeswitch/src/mod/applications/mod_soundtouch/mod_soundtouch.cpp:59:42: error: template argument 1 is invalid
/usr/local/src/freeswitch/src/mod/applications/mod_soundtouch/mod_soundtouch.cpp:59:56: error: expected unqualified-id before '=' token
/usr/local/src/freeswitch/src/mod/applications/mod_soundtouch/mod_soundtouch.cpp:60:42: error: template argument 1 is invalid
/usr/local/src/freeswitch/src/mod/applications/mod_soundtouch/mod_soundtouch.cpp:60:56: error: expected unqualified-id before '=' token
/usr/local/src/freeswitch/src/mod/applications/mod_soundtouch/mod_soundtouch.cpp:61:41: error: template argument 1 is invalid
/usr/local/src/freeswitch/src/mod/applications/mod_soundtouch/mod_soundtouch.cpp:61:55: error: expected unqualified-id before '=' token
/usr/local/src/freeswitch/src/mod/applications/mod_soundtouch/mod_soundtouch.cpp:62:41: error: template argument 1 is invalid
/usr/local/src/freeswitch/src/mod/applications/mod_soundtouch/mod_soundtouch.cpp:62:55: error: expected unqualified-id before '=' token

Do I need to use a specific namespace for the right and left arguments?  Where are these defined?  Or is something else wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

Regards,

Jon

Comment: This couldn't possibly be your program. You are missing an `#` before an include, and overall as presented your code compiles.